# how to update only first character in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have follwoing data in MyTable

```
ID = 1, No1 = 23, No2 = 45, D = 1
ID = 2, No1 = 12, No2 = 5, D = 1
ID = 3, No1 = 14, No2 = 4, D = 1
ID = 4, No1 = 41, No2 = 12, D = 1
ID = 5, No1 = 2, No2 = 25, D = 1
ID = 6, No1 = 3, No2 = 96, D = 1
```

I want to update only first character of column No1 if it is 1 then it should be 0
as following

```
ID = 1, No1 = 23, No2 = 45, D = 1
ID = 2, No1 = 02, No2 = 5, D = 1
ID = 3, No1 = 04, No2 = 4, D = 1
ID = 4, No1 = 41, No2 = 12, D = 1
ID = 5, No1 = 2, No2 = 25, D = 1
ID = 6, No1 = 3, No2 = 96, D = 1
```

Now I am using C# to do this, I Open all records of `No1` From `MyTable` and checking in C# manually using `loop` if I found first character as 1 then I make string and update database .. and it is working but problem is I have `10000 X 100` Records in `Mytable` so every time loop will run 10000 X 100 times and result is application low performance,
I just want to ask is "there is any method to update Only fist character of a `No1` coloumn by using only SQL and with C#...

Update :
All datatypes of MyTable are int

Comment: You should be able to do this in a single SQL update statement using a WHERE clause for the No1 column. Also, what is the exact column type of No1?

Comment: How often is this going to be run? Is it a one-off requirement? How large are the values in No1? Is 100 a possibility?

Comment: @chrisb it will run just i press button update and No1 may 0 to 9999, i just want to update first char 1 to 0 and all other remain number will same like 1111 will 0111 or 12 to 02

Comment: If your Datatype for No1 is INT, then if you find and replace value begins with 1, SQLServer will store the value as 2 in case of 12 not as 02.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Datatype for No1 is INT, then if you find and replace value begins with 1, SQLServer will store the value as 2 in case of 12 not as 02.

```
update #MyTable set No1 = case when left(No1,1) = 1 then stuff(NO1,1,1,0) else No1 end  --Update
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given we know the value ranges from 0 to 9999, the query could look like:

```
update MyTable
set No1 = CASE WHEN No1 between 10 and 19     THEN No1 - 10
               WHEN No1 between 100 and 199   THEN No1 - 100
               WHEN No1 between 1000 and 1999 THEN No1 - 1000 END
where No1 between 10 and 19    
   or No1 between 100 and 199  
   or No1 between 1000 and 1999
```

If its run really often, you may need to look at adding appropriate indexes and so on, but a quick test suggests its not too bad.

Comment: Havnt tested it, but it looks alright. Should be the best way to go.

Comment: @chrisb it is giving "Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of substring function." Error...., All datatypes are int

Comment: @chrusb OK i Solved this, changed int to nvarchar(MAX), Thanks ... and +1

Comment: Well, if you're sure - I updated the answer with one that can work more efficiently with your desired int column.

Answer (score 0):

As per **@chrisb Old Answer** it is worked on `nvarchar(MAX)`,

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET No1 = '0' + SUBSTRING(No1, 2, LEN(No1) - 1)
WHERE No1 LIKE '1%'
```