# What is the updatetext equivalent for a varchar(max) field?

Tags: sql-server, text, sql-server-2012, varchar, clob

I have used the `updatetext` command for a text (clob) field.
What is something most similar that would work for a `varchar(max)` field?

Comment: Why on Earth are you storing 1GB of text data into a single field?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26687999/1507566

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to update only first character in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26687762/how-to-update-only-first-character-in-sql-server)

Comment: You can change the logging to SIMPLE before the UPDATE, and then change it back.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the new `.WRITE` part of an UPDATE clause. See [under "Updating Large Value Data Types" in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql#updating-large-value-data-types).

However:

> ".WRITE updates that insert or append new data are minimally logged if the database recovery model is set to bulk-logged or simple. Minimal logging is not used when existing values are updated."

...so I don't think you'll reduce your transaction log size if you're actually replacing data.

However, that's exactly the same as with the old `UPDATETEXT` method, according to the [Transaction Log documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server#MinimallyLogged). They're both mentioned as operations that can be minimally logged, but in either case if you *update* existing data you won't get minimal logging:

> - Partial updates to large value data types, using the .WRITE clause in the UPDATE statement when inserting or appending new data. Note that minimal logging is not used when existing values are updated. For more information about large value data types, see Data Types (Transact-SQL).
> - WRITETEXT and UPDATETEXT statements when inserting or appending new data into the text, ntext, and image data type columns. Note that minimal logging is not used when existing values are updated.

Comment: The documentation of the UPDATETEXT command doesn't seem to specify whether it minimizes logging.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/updatetext-transact-sql   Even though this .WRITE tool may not do what the OP wants, +1 because it's something new and cool to me.

Comment: @TabAlleman Just in case you're interested, I found the documentation on what gets minimally logged with WRITE and WRITETEXT/UPDATETEXT and updated the answer. My vague recollection was right: if you're changing existing content, you don't get minimal logging in either case.

Answer (score -1):

Do you like some thing like that?

```
create table #t (f varchar(max) ) 

insert into #t values ('Xeiou')
insert into #t values ('Xbcdefghijlmnopq')
insert into #t values ('X')

update #t
set f = 'A' + SUBSTRING(f,2,len(f)-1)
where f is not null

select * from #t

drop table #t


f
----------------------
Aeiou
Abcdefghijlmnopq
A
```

I figure that is the only way to update a varchar field partially.